# Return 1 or 0 as a subquery field with EXISTS?

Tags: sql

I'm struggling to figure this one out.
What I want to do is like so:

```
select [fields],
       ((select <criteria>) return 0 if no rows returned, return 1 if any rows returned) as SubqueryResult
where a=b
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In T-sql you can use Exists clause for the given requirement as:

```
select [fields],
       case when exists (select <criteria> from <tablename> ) then 1 
            else 0 
            end as SubqueryResult
from <tablename>     
where a=b
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
select [fields],
       case when (select COUNT(*) from YourTable with criteria)>0 then 
            1 
       else 
            0 
       end 
       as SubqueryResult
where a=b
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried both and they both work. I'm using T-SQL, is EXISTS not more efficient than COUNT?

Comment: exists returns result as soon as it finds record with matching where-clause while count needs to scan whole table to determine count. So exists is faster

Answer (score 0):

Also in TSQL you can do it using `ISNULL()` and `SELECT TOP 1`:

```
select [fields],
       ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM YourTable WHERE <criteria> ),0)
       as SubqueryResult
where a=b
```